# Any way to bulk add Forward or Store & Forward in Lotus Notes?

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

Undergoing a change in email systems, is there a way to script or bulk ass forwarding addresses for Notes accounts? Currently, the process is to open each individual NSF file then add a rule that forwards all documents to the appropriate target address, but this would be extremely time consuming (and annoying) to do for 1000+ accounts. Is there a way to do this faster or in bulk?

Domino/Notes Version is 8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the mail type within the person documents in the Domino Directory.  Instead of having Notes as the mail system, set it to Other Internet Mail and enter the forwarding address.  You could also do this via a little LotusScript pretty quickly, or by creating a Notes Agent to help change all of the person documents.

If for some reason you *need* to have the change at the individual mail NSF level, you could write a Lotusscript formula to run as mail arrives and then forward as needed.  To push that out to all users you could just change the master mail template from which all the mail files inherit.

Comment: I never did find a solution for this so the Lotus admin did all the forwarding manually it seems. I don't have any experience in LotuScripts, but I'll look into them next time I come upon such an issue.